# Round function and add "$"

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched and tried several times but still can't get it. How do I prepend "$" and round the value to the nearest 100th of a decimal. Example: `$100.00`

```
<script>
  $.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data, status) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
      if (data[i].id == "unit") {
        $("#unit").html(parseFloat(data[i].price_usd) * 500000);
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: String concatentation and some grouping parentheses and the `.toFixed(2)` method are all you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as dollars currency string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Really? That's the first result when you google "format currency JS"

Comment: I tried the .toFixed(2) seems to not work

Comment: actually in data the string "unit" is not there. please check once

Answer (score 2):

Use Number.prototype.toFixed() to make fixed number of decimals, concatinate strings as usual, because toFixed returns string:

```js
function toCurrency(value = 0, symbol = '$', onEnd = false) {
  if (onEnd) {
    return Number(value).toFixed(2) + symbol;
  }
  return symbol + Number(value).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(toCurrency(123.7483));
console.log(toCurrency(123));
console.log(toCurrency(123, ' USD', true));
```

Comment: To make your code a little DRYer, might I suggest the following edit? `const cost = Number(value).toFixed(2); return onEnd ? cost + symbol : symbol + cost;`

Comment: i don't think it is necessary on any way.